# How to remove the default background color for pressed PopupMenu items?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I've added rounded corners to a `PopupMenu` and it looks good, except now when I press a menu item, I get the ugly effect shown here:

[image]

In this example, while my finger is touching the third item, Android adds a default color behind the item, which shows through at the rounded corners. It also adds a rounded background to the item text, which partially covers the "glow" around the radio button.

This is my XML style for rounding the corners of the `PopupMenu`:

```
<style name="popover" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/alert_rounded_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#F9F9F9</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#F9F9F9</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#F9F9F9</item>
</style>
```

And alert_rounded_dark.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#2B2B2B" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

It looks like Android is applying the rounded background style to the subviews of the popup menu, including the menu items and the menu item text. I tried to stop that by setting `itemBackground` to `@android:color/transparent` or `@null`, but that had no effect.

I tried changing the `background` attribute to `windowBackground`, `popupBackground` or `panelBackground`, but then the whole `PopupMenu` and its items were transparent.

I had a similar issue when rounding the corners of `ListView` rows, which I solved with this function of `ListView`:

```
this.listView?.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent)
```

I think this corresponds to the `listSelector` XML attribute, but I don't see a similar function or attribute in the class reference for `PopupMenu`, and using the `listSelector` attribute for a `PopupMenu` does nothing.

Is there another way to visually clean this up? I think stopping the inheritance of the rounded corner background *and* removing the pressed color would be best, but addressing either one should help a lot.

**UPDATE**

I found that changing `itemBackground` to the same color as the menu background stopped the system color from appearing behind items when pressing them (the four light gray corners you see in the picture), but that killed the rounded corners by adding an opaque, square background to every item. Then I tried setting `itemBackground` to a drawable selector that sets every state to the `alert_rounded_dark` drawable, to preserve the rounded corners, but that didn't suppress the system pressed color like setting a background color did.

Comment: one thing comes to mind is : if you need this much of personalization in view, why not using custom dialog which you will define the XML from scratch and have a lot more control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you apply the `popover` style to your PopupMenu?

---

If you use a `ContextThemeWrapper`, you can't directly apply PopupMenu style.

You need to assign your `popover` style to the `popupMenuStyle` attribute in the theme overlay. Here is how you can do it:

styles.xml

```xml
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.PopupMenu" parent="">
        <!-- if using android.widget.PopupMenu -->
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <!-- if using androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu -->
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>

        <!-- Other attributes -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#F9F9F9</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#F9F9F9</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#F9F9F9</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/alert_rounded_dark</item>
    </style>
```

And use it like so:

```kotlin
val menu = PopupMenu(
    // Using "ContextThemeWrapper" for PopupMenu customization
    ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_PopupMenu),
    view // Your anchor view
)
menu.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_id)
menu.show()
```

Here is how it looks on my end:

[image: popup_styling_example]

Bonus:

If you wish to further customize `RadioButton` inside the `PopupMenu`, you can add `radioButtonStyle` attribute to the theme overlay, like so:

```xml
    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.PopupMenu" parent="">
        ...
        <item name="radioButtonStyle">@style/YourCustomRadioButton</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks @Veniamin for the thorough answer and picture. It worked perfectly!